# Angular v13, не отрабатывает вызываемый http метод из сервиса

Tags: http, angular, angular2

Из HTML компонента вызываю метод в сервисе: `<button (click)="myService.addData(item)"></button>`

В сервисе:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
  }

  constructor (
    protected http: HttpClient,
  ) {}

  addData(item: Item): Observable<Item> {
    console.log(item) // Отрабатывает
    return this.http.post<Item>('/api/v1/add-item', item, this.httpOptions); // Метод не вызывается
  }
}
```

Подскажите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было подписаться на вызываемый метод из сервиса, чтобы инициировать вызов.
Вызывать метод не напрямую из сервиса, а из компонента: `<button (click)="addData(item)"></button>`
В компоненте:

```js
addPeriod (item: Item): void {
    this.myService.addPeriod(item)
    .subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params)
    });
}
```